# Crontab not executing script inside Alpine Container

Tags: docker, cron, alpine-linux

I'm trying to build a very simple Alpine Docker container, where I want to execute a python script every minute using cron.

I can correctly create the container, copy the files and create a cron entry, however the main.log file is never created, so I'm suspecting that cron is not executing the script and I don't know why.

My crontab.txt

```
* * * * * python main.py >> main.log
```

My python script:

```
print("Hello World")
```

My DockerFile (I added the last line because my understanding is that otherwise the container will stop after setting the crontab)

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
COPY . .
RUN /usr/bin/crontab crontab.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

My Docker Compose file:

```
version: "3.8"    
services:
  app:
    build: .
```

Inside the container I can do an `ls` and I see

```
/code # ls
Dockerfile          crontab.txt         docker-compose.yml  main.py
```

Doing `crontab -l` correctly shows the crontab entry

```
/code # crontab -l
* * * * * python main.py >> main.log
```

And manually executing the script correctly creates the log file

```
/code # python main.py >> main.log && cat main.log
Hello World
```

However if I don't manually execute the script, then the logfile is never created, making me think that the script is not being executed every minute.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This might help - https://blog.thesparktree.com/cron-in-docker

Comment: Your `ENTRYPOINT` doesn't actually run the cron daemon as the main container process.  You need to replace this (I'd recommend using `CMD` as a little easier to debug) with the command to run the cron daemon in the foreground.  A Docker container is not a VM and doesn't run "services" _per se_, and I wouldn't normally expect to get a shell inside a container.